# How to convert object to int in jupyter (pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert object to int in jupyter (pandas)?

```
dataset['Gender'] = dataset['Gender'].astype(str).astype(int)
```

[image]

Comment: word `Female` is not any kind of figure and cannot be float or int, - that's why you get the error message.
P.S. object in pandas, - means string (text)

Comment: to convert 'Female' to 0 and 'Male' to 1, try `dataset['Gender'] = dataset['Gender'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x=='Female' else 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of options, you can map the values using a dictionary or a can factorize all unique values.

`dataset['Gender'].str.lower().map({'female':0, 'male':1})` # assuming you have only male and female.

`dataset['Gender'] = dataset['Gender'].factorize()[0]`